# Using tidyverse and matconv to convert Matlab code to R code

Tags: r, matlab, tidyverse, purrr

The `Matlab` code can be converted to `R` code using the following command

```r
library(matconv)

mat2r(
   inMat           = "A.m"
  , pathOutR       = "A.R"
  , funcConverters = NULL
  , dataConverters = NULL
  , verbose        = 1
)

mat2r(
   inMat           = "B.m"
  , pathOutR       = "B.R"
  , funcConverters = NULL
  , dataConverters = NULL
  , verbose        = 1
)
```

However, I'm looking some more efficient code something like below:

```r
library(purrr)
dir(path = ".", pattern = "*.m", full.names = FALSE) %>%
map(
  .x = .
, .f = mat2r(
           inMat           = .
          , pathOutR       = paste0(., ".R")
          , funcConverters = NULL
          , dataConverters = NULL
          , verbose        = 1
        )
    )
```

Which is not working for me. Any hint please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following :

```
dir(path = ".", pattern = "*.m") %>%
  purrr::map(.f = ~mat2r(
        inMat           = .x
      , pathOutR       = sub('m$', "R", .x)
      , funcConverters = NULL
      , dataConverters = NULL
      , verbose        = 1
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak for useful answer. However, in my actual problem I got the following error: `Error in gsub("end", sprintf("length(%s)", varName), lin) : 
  invalid 'replacement' argument`. Any hint!

Comment: Are you using some other code other than the one in the answer? I am not sure from where the error is coming regarding `gsub`, `sprintf` etc since we are not using those functions here. Perhaps, the error is coming from one of the matlab files while conversion?